# Change order of String array based on order of long array

Tags: java, arrays

Basically, I'm trying to make a high-score display, comparing names and times (faster is better). I take the array of times, and sort them based on value (smallest to greatest). I then want the names to be re-arranged according to the times, which I am having trouble doing.

So basically, I want the input to be something like this:

> John--8 
> Sally--5
>  James--2 
> Fred--4

And the output to be:

> James--2
>  Fred--4
>  Sally--5
>  John--8

Currently, the output is:

> John--2
>  Sally--4
>  James--5
>  Fred--8

Here is my code (note: you will need to have [these text documents](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8wPABZ2CJFGQkpLU2FvOW9fWjQ)):

```
//not actually sure which of these import statements are really necessary, lol
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Container;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.*;
import java.util.Vector;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.Canvas;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.io.*;

import java.util.Arrays;

class HallOfFame extends JFrame implements ActionListener 
{

    private static final int FRAME_WIDTH    = 300;
    private static final int FRAME_HEIGHT   = 350;

    int numberOfRows=20;

    String[] name = new String[100];
    String[] time = new String[100];

    //long[] longArrayTime = new long[100];

    String[] saneTime = new String[100];

    /*it's been a */long[] longTime = new long[100];

    long second;
    long minute;
    long hour;
    long miliseconds;
    //Declare your objects here...

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        HallOfFame frame = new HallOfFame();  
        frame.setVisible(true); // Display the frame
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")  //without this line, a warning appears. i can find no need for it and it's annoying, so i got rid of it :P (It is in relation to the table)
    public HallOfFame( ) 
    {  

        try 
        {
            File inFile= new File("names.txt");
            FileReader fileReader= new FileReader(inFile);
            BufferedReader bufReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

            for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
            {
                name[i]=bufReader.readLine();

            }
            bufReader.close();

        }
        catch(IOException tada)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error loading high scores. Please ensure file system is accesible, and that 'name.txt' exists");
        }

        try 
        {
            File inFile= new File("times.txt");
            FileReader fileReader= new FileReader(inFile);
            BufferedReader bufReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

            for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
            {
                time[i]=bufReader.readLine();

            }
            bufReader.close();

        }
        catch(IOException tada)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error loading high scores. Please ensure file system is accesible, and that 'name.txt' exists");
        }

        //finished reading scores
        for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
        {
            if(time[i]==null||time[i].equals(("0")))
            {
                time[i]="3699989"; //a very large value so that non-existant values are at the end of a sorted array
            }

            longTime[i] = Long.parseLong(time[i]);
        }
        Arrays.sort(longTime);


        for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
        {
            second = (longTime[i] / 1000) % 60;
            minute = (longTime[i] / (1000 * 60)) % 60;
            hour = (longTime[i] / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24;
            miliseconds = Long.parseLong((""+longTime[i]).substring(0,2));

            saneTime[i] = String.format("%02d:%02d:%d", minute, second, miliseconds);
        }

        // set the frame properties
        setTitle("High Scores");
        setSize(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setResizable(false);
        Image icon = new ImageIcon("trophy.png").getImage();   //why does this not work????
        setIconImage(icon);

        Object columns[] = { "Rank", "Time", "Name" };
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(columns, 0);

        for(int i=0;i<numberOfRows;i++)
        {
            if(time[i]=="3699989")//stop adding scores when array is empty (this large number is "empty" as 0 is defined to it above to make sorting the array work)
            {
                break;
            }
            Vector row = new Vector(numberOfRows);
            row.add((i+1));
            //row.add(time[i]);
            row.add(saneTime[i]);
            row.add(name[i]);
            model.addRow( row );
        }

        // set the content pane properties
        Container contentPane = getContentPane();   
        contentPane.setLayout(new GridLayout());
        contentPane.setBackground(Color.white);

        JTable table = new JTable( model );
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        contentPane.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        for(int i=0;i<numberOfRows;i++)
        {
            table.setRowHeight(i, 30);
        }

        //create and place items frame's content pane

        // register 'Exit' upon closing as default close operation
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) // Actions
    {      
        JButton clickedButton = (JButton) event.getSource();        

    }   
}
```

Comment: Basically, use the right data type for the job: 1) Create a class to capture name/time/etc; 2) Don't use a string to represent time - ideally use something from java.time, but possibly use an integer number of milliseconds or whatever. You can then easily sort the whole array or collection of items however you want.

Comment: Don't use parallel arrays/lists. Java is an Object-Oriented language. *Use it!* Create a class with your values, have a single array/list of objects of that class. Now you can sort to your hearts content, and values will always stay together.

Comment: @JonSkeet I am using a long value in # of miliseconds to represent time. It just has to be a string first to be read from the file, then it is converted to long. Another class will also capture name and time, it is just not shown here, as the other class will just save it to this file

Comment: @Andreas Oh dear... I have absolutely no idea how to do that. I'm still a beginner to java

Comment: @Blaine: So why are you storing that in an array? You can parse it as soon as you read it. You've presented too much code to be worth reading in detail, but I'm utterly convinced that sorting out your data model will make it *much* easier to achieve your goal.

Comment: @Blaine: If you don't know how to create your own class to capture the name/time/etc of a single game, I'd suggest concentrating on *that* instead of continuing GUI programming without knowing the basics of the language. Get hold of a good book and read it - and I'd suggest starting with console apps, as they're considerably simpler than GUIs, for learning the core parts of the language.

Comment: @JonSkeet Sorry about the giant stack of code... couldn't figure out how to skim it down in a meaningful way. Storing it in a string temporarily made it eaiser at the time. It's an unnecessary step, but shouldn't make a difference in the long run.

Comment: @JonSkeet I do know how to create a class to capture name time, etc. I'm just saving it to a file and then reading it again because it should stay the same over multiple sessions. That's not really my issue right now

Comment: @Blaine If you know how to create a class, why did you say *"Oh dear... I have absolutely no idea how to do that"* when I suggested you do exactly that?

Comment: @Andreas haha, I meant that I don't understand the part about having a single array of objects in that class. How to do that/what it is supposed to accomplish

Comment: It's meant to make it considerably easier to sort - because then you're sorting *one* array rather than an array of names, and array of times etc separately.

Comment: @Blaine Instead of having two independent arrays, `String[] name` and `String[] time`, you create a class (`e.g. NameTime`) with two fields, `String name` and `String time`, then have a single array of that class, `NameTime[] data`.

Comment: @Andreas oh, ok, I see a bit of the concept. Do you have by any chance a link to some page that explains how to do this in more detail?

Comment: @Blaine Yes I do: See [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39445702/5221149).

Comment: @Andreas yes, I know that's what you are discribing, but I don't understand the logic behind it, which is necessary for me to implement it and understand what i'm doing

Comment: The logic behind *what*? How to create a class? How to create an array? How to sort an array? Follow [advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39445497#comment66213050_39445497) by @JonSkeet: *Get hold of a good book and read it.*

Comment: the logic behind combining 2 arrays and using a comparator. prety much i'm asking for that good book to readd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As many already mentioned you should realy try to use another data structure. I will try to keep your logic as it was and make some small improvements where needed.

```
//not actually sure which of these import statements are really necessary, lol
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Container;

import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Vector;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

class HallOfFame extends JFrame implements ActionListener 
{

    private static final int FRAME_WIDTH    = 300;
    private static final int FRAME_HEIGHT   = 350;

    int numberOfRows=20;

    String[] name = new String[100];
    String[] time = new String[100];

    //long[] longArrayTime = new long[100];

    String[] saneTime = new String[100];

    /*it's been a */long[] longTime = new long[100];

    long second;
    long minute;
    long hour;
    long miliseconds;
     //Declare your objects here...

     public static void main(String[] args) 
     {
         HallOfFame frame = new HallOfFame();  
         frame.setVisible(true); // Display the frame
      }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")  //without this line, a warning appears. i can find no need for it and it's annoying, so i got rid of it :P (It is in relation to the table)
    public HallOfFame( ) 
    {  

        try 
        {
            File inFile= new File("names.txt");
            FileReader fileReader= new FileReader(inFile);
            BufferedReader bufReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

            for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
            {
                 name[i]=bufReader.readLine();

            }
            bufReader.close();

            }
            catch(IOException tada)
            {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error loading high scores. Please ensure file system is accesible, and that 'name.txt' exists");
          }

          try 
          {
           File inFile= new File("times.txt");
           FileReader fileReader= new FileReader(inFile);
           BufferedReader bufReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

           for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
           {
            time[i]=bufReader.readLine();

        }
        bufReader.close();

    }
    catch(IOException tada)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error loading high scores. Please ensure file system is accesible, and that 'name.txt' exists");
    }

    //finished reading scores
    for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
    {
        if(time[i]==null||time[i].equals(("0")))
        {
            time[i]="3699989"; //a very large value so that non-existant values are at the end of a sorted array
        }

        longTime[i] = Long.parseLong(time[i]);
    }
    //Arrays.sort(longTime); removed

    /* removed and replaced with a method which returns HH:mm:ss for given milliseconds
    for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
    {
        second = (longTime[i] / 1000) % 60;
        minute = (longTime[i] / (1000 * 60)) % 60;
        hour = (longTime[i] / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24;
        miliseconds = Long.parseLong((""+longTime[i]).substring(0,2));

        saneTime[i] = String.format("%02d:%02d:%d", minute, second, miliseconds);
    }*/

    class Player implements Comparable<Player>{     //added a class player with the atr. name and time
        String name;
        Long time;

        Player(String name, Long time){
            this.name = name;
            this.time = time;
        }
        @Override
        public int compareTo(Player p) {        // a compareTo method which is needed to sort a list of players
          return time.compareTo(p.time);        // sorting by time, you can change this to sort by name age or sth.else
        }
    }

    ArrayList<Player> playerslist = new ArrayList<>(); // an ArrayList to hold your data  
    for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
        Player p = new Player(name[i],longTime[i]);
        playerslist.add(p);
    }
    Collections.sort(playerslist);

    // set the frame properties
    setTitle("High Scores");
    setSize(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setResizable(false);
    Image icon = new ImageIcon("trophy.png").getImage();   //why does this not work????
    setIconImage(icon);

    Object columns[] = { "Rank", "Time", "Name" };
    DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(columns, 0);

       for(int i=0;i<numberOfRows;i++)
       {
           if(playerslist.get(i).time >1000000)//stop adding scores when array is empty (this large number is "empty" as 0 is defined to it above to make sorting the array work)
          {
            break;
           }
          Vector row = new Vector(numberOfRows);
          row.add((i+1));
          //row.add(time[i]);
          row.add(convertSecondsToHMmSs(playerslist.get(i).time));
          row.add(playerslist.get(i).name);
          model.addRow( row );
       }

    // set the content pane properties
    Container contentPane = getContentPane();   
    contentPane.setLayout(new GridLayout());
    contentPane.setBackground(Color.white);

    JTable table = new JTable( model );
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
    contentPane.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    for(int i=0;i<numberOfRows;i++)
    {
        table.setRowHeight(i, 30);
    }

    //create and place items frame's content pane

    // register 'Exit' upon closing as default close operation
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) // Actions
    {      
      JButton clickedButton = (JButton) event.getSource();        

    }

     public static String convertSecondsToHMmSs(long millis) {       // method to change milliseconds to HH:mm:ss
    return String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", 
    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis),
    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis) -  
    TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis)), 
    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis) - 
     TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis))); 
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you!! This was the example I was looking for. The one that showed how to actually use it in the overall program

Answer (score 2):

Create a class which has the name and time as properties

```
public class Highscore {
    private String name;
    private long time;
    public Highscore(String name, long time) {
        this.name = name;
        this.time = time;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
    public long getTime() {
        return this.time;
    }
}
```

Then put all your Highscore objects into a collection. E.g.: `ArrayList` and sort those Objects using a `Comparator`.

```
Collections.sort(highscores, new Comparator<Highscore>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Highscore hs1, Highscore hs2) {
        return Long.compare(hs1.getTime(), hs2.getTime());
    }
});
```

Or as suggested by @Andreas, if you're using Java 8 you can use the shortened expression to sort your `ArrayList`:

```
highscores.sort(Comparator.comparing(Highscore::getTime))
```

Comment: Or `highscores.sort(Comparator.comparing(Highscore::getTime))` in Java 8.

Comment: To compare two `long` values, use [`Long.compare(hs1.getTime(), hs2.getTime())`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#compare-long-long-). Of course, you'll need a getter method for any of this to work.

Comment: I suspect this solves the problem, but I honestly don't know how to use it

Comment: @Blaine It surely is okay not to understand something, but why don't you simply search it on the internet? The answer states "...sort those Objects using a Comparator". If you don't know what a Comparator is, then open a new tab, open a search engine, enter something like "java using comparator". And while your at a website like that, you can go on and read it's other articles, learning the coding style of java.

Answer (score -2):

A simple solution, which isn't optimzed, would be to rearrange your array (swap name and value positions) and then sort it (Arrays,sort)

```
    public class SortArray {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String [] arr = new String[4];

        arr[0] = "John--8";
        arr[1] = "Sally--5";
        arr[2] = "James--2";
        arr[3] = "Fred--4";
        sortArr(arr);
        for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i){
            String []  splitArr = arr[i].split("--");
            System.out.println(splitArr[1] +"--"+splitArr[0]);
        }
    }
    public static void sortArr(String [] arr) {

        int len = arr.length;

        for(int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
            String []  splitArr = arr[i].split("--");

            arr[i] = splitArr[1] +"--" +splitArr[0];

        }

        Arrays.sort(arr);


    }

}
```

The output is

```
James--2
Fred--4
Sally--5
John--8
```

Comment: This is a bad solution to the problem, IMO. Using proper object orientation is far superior to shoving everything into a string.

Comment: actually, at the moment, I perfer a less proper solution that I actually understand with my limited knowlage

Comment: still, the issue with this is that both values are in the same variable

Comment: @Blaine: I would *strongly* advise you not to just keep going without learning the basics of the language. Take a bit of time on each step and you'll avoid getting yourself into deep water too quickly.

Comment: @Blaine So just split the final (sorted) array and put them in the name and time arrays.

Comment: @dsp_user that would work, but at the moment, the data is being taken from two seperate arrays

Comment: @Blaine Don't go with a hack solution like this, since it will sort the time values as strings, e.g. `10` sorts before `9`, so it won't work right.